# Migration of mysql dates in integer format

Tags: mysql, database-migration

I want to migrate dates from integer format to DATETIME.

My dates in my old database have the following format:

olddb.table.date = 20131114 (INT)
olddb.table.time = 900 (INT) (9 AM, 24h clock)

new database:

newdb.table.datetime = 2013-11-14 9:00:00 (DATETIME)

How would I migrate this with purely SQL?

Comment: You need to do a little bit of integer arithmetic (using integer division and modulo) to extract all the fields and then use them to create the datetime

Comment: @acfrancis Could you provide an example?

Comment: Can you give us more examples of your time part ? How is stored 23h ? 10h30 ? Do you store seconds ?

Comment: As I said in the post, 24h clock, so it's stored as '2300'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(DATE(olddb.table.date),' ',TIME(olddb.table.time*100)) AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: If it works reliably, it certainly is a lot simpler than my solution.

Comment: It does, I have, just now, tested it with ~20 different combinations.

Comment: MySQL is smarter than I thought. I always use strings with dashes and colons to be clear.

Comment: Even better... How do I get it working btw if seconds are included in the TIME column too? (i need to do this migration several times across several kinds of columns)

Comment: seconds is not a problem. as you can see, i multiplied your time column by 100 because 9am was 900. The time function takes and integer an splits it into pairs of digits starting from the end. So 900 = 9m00s. Multiply it by 100 it becomes 90000 = 9h00m00s. 155534 = 15h55m34s = 15:55:34.

Comment: Alright so I wouldn't have to multiply the time column at all to convert it to datetime, if it is already included seconds. Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date part with `STR_TO_DATE` ([MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)):

```
STR_TO_DATE(olddb.table.date, "%Y%m%d")
```

And for the time part, you can use the same function :

```
STR_TO_DATE(olddb.table.time, "%h%i")
```

Then, you can concatenate date and time parts and apply function to concatenation result :

```
STR_TO_DATE(concatenated_value, "%Y%m%d%h%i")
```

Where `concatenated_value` is built with :

```
CONCAT(olddb.table.date, olddb.table.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cast(
    concat(
        table.date div 10000, '-',
        lpad((table.date mod 10000) div 100, 2, '0'), '-',
        lpad(table.date mod 100, 2, '0'), ' ',
        table.time div 100, ':',
        lpad(table.time mod 100, 2, '0'))
as datetime)
```

Here's a working example:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff75/1

Comment: This is overly complicated, see my answer for a cleaner, simpler solution.